# glxinfo: OpenGL renderer string::Chromium

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu, virtualbox

```
$ glxinfo | grep rend

direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
```

What does "Chromium" means in the context of `glxinfo`?

I used to see something like "Mesa DRI Intel" or "software" etc. This must be something new?

Comment: Running inside a VM?

Comment: @genpfault right, vbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is something very old. It is basically the [chromium open source project](http://chromium.sf.net) (not to be confused with google's browser enginge with the same name).

Chromium provides a generic framework for OpenGL stream forwarding and maniuplation. One of the main goals of chromium was providing a transparent middleware for distributed rendering. However, the project is more or less dead since 2009.

Parts of chromium were used by other projects. The most likely place to see that "chromium" renderer string is the opengl layer of VirtualBox, which uses part of chromium's OpenGL library and dispatch mechanism to forward OpenGL calls from the guest to the host.